# Transformar colunas em linhas pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

Preciso fazer algumas modificações em um dataframe porém não estou conseguindo. Estou usando o pandas.

Tenho a tabela abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas quero que ela fique assim?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Answer (score 3):

Boa tarde, você consegue fazer isto utilizando o comando `melt`

Segue abaixo o teste que fiz:

*Importa os dados de entrada*

```
import pandas
data = pandas.DataFrame({'Local':['são paulo','rio','bahia'], '01/09/2007': [1,2,0], '01/10/2007': [0,1,0], '01/11/2007': [2,1,1], '01/12/2007': [2,0,3], '01/01/2008': [0,1,1], 'contato':['2345-1244','5422-1244','2345-8674']})
```

Aplica o comando `melt` nos indices, setando `Local` e `contato` como ids e adicionando a variável `mes` com o valor `quantidade` dentro do novo dataFrame, além disto já faço a ordenação pelo Local e quantidade de modo descendente

```
data = pandas.melt(data.reset_index(), id_vars=['Local', 'contato'], 
var_name='mes', value_name='quantidade').sort(['Local','quantidade'], ascending=False)
```

O novo dataFrame foi criado, porém ainda temos algumas linhas indesejáveis que contém `index` no valor, então simplesmente faço a remoção destas linhas

```
data = data[data.mes.str.contains("index") == False]
```

Segue o resultado

[image]

Espero ter ajudado
Abraço

Answer (score 0):

Olá, tudo bem, eu achei uma solução bem bacana, que me resolveu o problema vou postar a imagem aqui!, df.stack()

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]